# C++ - Assign Complex to double

Tags: c++

I want to do this:

```
Complex c(1, 2);
double d = c;
```

I tried to do

```
friend double operator=(double& d, Complex& c){...}
```

But got errors that assignment operator must be a non-static member, but how to assign Complex to double?

Comment: I'd ask myself - what does it mean when you convert a double from a complex variable? Is it the real or imaginary part? Or what?

Comment: Not matter, this is just a training with C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write an implicit conversion operator in `Complex` :

```
class Complex {
public:
    operator double () const {
        //...
    }
};
```